# Powershell Replace function is treating commas as dots when replacing

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, batch-file, scripting

So I have like 100 files of different types, those files contain the following strings:

**1.2.0.0**

and

**1,2,0,0**

I'm only trying to replace **1.2.0.0** with **1.2.0.1**, ONLY the strings with dots but powershell is also replacing these strings **1,2,0,0** with **1.2.0.0**
Why is Powershell treating commas like periods?

```
get-childitem $OUTPUT_PATH -recurse -include *.rc,*.cs,*.rtf,*.sql | 
select -expand fullname |
foreach {
  (Get-Content $_) -replace '1.2.0.0','1.2.0.1' | Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: The `.` in a regular expression means "any character". If you mean literal `.`, you need to escape it as `\.`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That makes sense, I didn't know it was being treated as a regular expression. Thanks

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Is there a way to tell it to treat it as literal string instead of as a regular expression without having to escape it?

Comment: `-replace` operator is for regex. Use [string.replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) if you just want to manipulate strings without regex. Read more about replace operator by typing `get-help about_Comparison_Operators`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses a regular expression (see `help about_Comparison_Operators`). The `.` in a regular expression means "any character." If you mean a literal `.`, you need to escape it using `\`, as in `\.`. For example:

```
'abc 1.2.0.0 def' -replace '1\.2\.0\.0', '1.2.0.1'
```

If you don't want to use a regular expression, use the `Replace` method of the `String` object. For example:

```
'abc 1.2.0.0 def'.Replace('1.2.0.0','1.2.0.1')
```

Both will output `abc 1.2.0.1 def`.